# Concerning The 'Price-Collecting Steiner Tree'

Tags: graph-theory, math-software, trees

I'm a Master student at the University of Leuven, Belgium. I have to make a report of a case concerning the 'Price-Collecting Steiner Tree'. We have our model and our restrictions. We are just looking for a program to run it and to find the optimal solution. So far we have only found one but the problem is that it runs only on Linux, and nor I, nor my teammates, have knowledge about how Linux operates. Does anyone know some software which runs on Windows or does anyone has some other useful information for me?

Many Thanks

Tim Moermans

Comment: The problem here is you haven't told us anything about what you want to do.  Are you wanting to work with graphs?  Or are you wanting to do linear programming?  Sage is a program that can do both.  It can not be installed directly into Windows, but you can install it on a virtual machine in Windows and there are instructions on the Sage website. It CAN be installed directly on a Mac.  You still have to learn how to use the program.  http://www.sagemath.org

Comment: In short the problem exists out 6000 nodes of which 308 are cities. The arcs represent roads. Our objective is to minimize traffic jams  during winter and each city mus be connected with another city (this is the subtree I guess). Given are the amount of salt available for each city and there's also a national depot of which cities can take salt. These are limited of course. Each city has it's costs for spreading salt and a minimum amount of salt has to be spread to make the road drivable.So now we have to connect each city in a tree (308 nodes) and the other nodes are optional.

Comment: Well, like I said, Sage might work.

Comment: Ok!Thank you!I'll look right into it!

Comment: Do you know some algorithm to solve a Steiner Tree in Networks or a Price-Collecting Steiner Tree? Or do you know some place where I can find it?

Comment: I've never heard of it.  You said you have a model.  I'm telling you that you can program it in Sage.  If you're looking for a program that already has it built in, I have no idea.

Comment: Might I suggest learning how to use Linux?  Find some old computer you don't mind destroying and install it on there (or run it off a live USB).  If you're a Masters student, it's a skill you might find helpful in the future (e.g. if you want to compare software run-times, use a server, etc.).  Ubuntu is a good choice for beginners.  If you get stuck, a lot of support can be found via Google or askubuntu.com.  It's not nearly as scary as you might think.

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones VirtualBox is, IMO, a much better learning environment that old computers and live USBs.

Comment: I wrote one on windows in 1987 ( c++) and updated it to work with new versions. But your post is very old !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually called prize-collecting Steiner tree problem. A Software for said problem that also works on Windows is here:
https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/STP_MAIN.php